# "history -c" doesn't work when called inside a script?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash, mingw-w64

I wrote a bash script to call a Python script that encrypts private data using AES, taking a filepath and a 256-bit password as the only arguments. After encryption is done, it clears the history so the password isn't sitting there in case I leave the terminal open. It looks something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python aesencrypt.py "$1" "$2"
history -c
echo "" > ~/.bash_history
```

The `~/.bash_history` file is cleared just fine, but if I run `history` after running this script then all of my history is still there (until I exit the terminal). Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Of course it doesn't -- it clears the history *of the shell running the script*, which is different from the history of *the shell that started the script*. The shell that started the script isn't even bash at all -- it could have been zsh, or dash, or it could have been started by a file manager or other external/C program that doesn't even *have* an idea of "history".

Comment: Anyhow, passing passwords on the command line is crazy-insecure even if there is no history at all. Any process running at the same time can sniff it out of the process tree, and there are programs that exist specifically to record and retain that history. Read your password direct from the TTY -- or even stdin is safer than the command line; so is an environment variable.

Comment: (well, I don't know about environment variable security *on Windows*, but on the last decade or two of UNIXes, they've only been exposed to the same user account, whereas command-line program arguments are visible to every program running under every account on the same machine unless you've gone to lengths like using separate process namespaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to clear history -- even though that's the most *obvious* way that passing a password on the command line exposes it, that action is giving a false sense of security: Passwords given on the command line are trivial to capture via other processes running on the same machine (even under untrusted accounts!) even without history involved at all.

Moreover, as you note, a shell can only modify *its own* in-memory state, not the in-memory state of the separate process that started it (which may not even be the same shell, or a shell at all!).

---

Instead, modify your Python program's calling convention to read the password direct from the TTY (as SSH does), or from the environment. For the latter, usage might look like:

```
# assumes you renamed aesencrypt.py to aesencrypt, ran chmod +x, and gave a valid shebang
password="somePassword" aesencrypt outFile
```

...and you would want to modify your Python script to do something like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
password = os.environ['password']

# ...put the rest of your logic here.
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how passing the password via system environment is more secure than passing it directly on the command line? i.e. I'm not sure how `password="hunter2" aesencrypt data.txt` is safer than `aesencrypt data.txt hunter2`. In both cases I have to include the password in the full command.

Comment: @HurricaneFist, yes, it's in the command both ways, but environment variables aren't visible to other users even though command-line arguments are. Try looking at `ps auxwww` from a different account; you'll see only `aesencrypt data.txt` shows up, without the `password` part.

Comment: (Also, if you read the bash manual, you'll note that there are plenty of options for suppressing history for sensitive commands -- if you turn on the appropriate flag, just starting your command with a space will keep it out of history... but *won't* keep it out of `ps`).

Comment: ...take a look at the documentation for `sshpass`, if you want an example of how this is done by some folks who have thought fairly hard about doing the best they can while fulfilling an innately-bad-for-security common request.

Comment: (And once again, the *best* choice is reading the password from the TTY; that's how SSH does it when you *aren't* doing something awful like using sshpass).